# How to use mockito to mock webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, mockito

I want to be able to do unit test for my Selenium integration tests and to do that I need to be able to mock the driver and the elements needed for the tests, this is a quick example of a function that returns the name of the element.

```
public class demo {

  private WebDriver mockDriver;
  private WebElement mockElement;

  @Before
  public void setUp(){
    this.mockDriver = mock(WebDriver.class);
    this.mockElement = mock(WebElement.class, withSettings().name("elementName"));
    when(this.mockDriver.findElement(By.id("testmock"))).thenReturn(mockElement);
  }

  public String getName(String id){
    WebElement testElement = mockDriver.findElement(By.id(id));
    return testElement.getAttribute("name");
  }

  @Test
  public void assertElementName() throws InterruptedException {
    Assert.assertTrue(getName("testmock").equals("elementName"));
  }
}
```

this gives me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the return in `getName()`.
I am obviously using this wrong but I can't figure out how. Anyone with some experience in this that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why on earth would you mock the WebDriver? I don't understand your comment on "unit test[ing] my Selenium integration tests."

Comment: Becous I want to make sure my functions that use the webdriver are correct. Like in this case, the function getName can't be tested if I dont have a mock driver to return my predefined element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what this piece of code does:

```
this.mockElement = mock(WebElement.class, withSettings().name("elementName"));
```

The `withSettings()` clause gives the mock object a name, meaning that certain error messages produced by Mockito will use this name. You are **not** setting any properties on the `WebElement` object.

So... when your code reaches this part:

```
return testElement.getAttribute("name");
```

It returns null because there is no attribute with that value. If you wanted to have an attribute, then you'd need to add something like the following:

```
when(this.mockElement.getAttribute("name")).thenReturn("elementName");
```

Comment: Okey, I see, i totaly missunderstood that part indeed.  So I have to build up my element with  "when" clauses?

Comment: @user2968166 Yes, any mock object is built up with a series of `when` clauses to define behaviour. Without a `when` clause, Mockito returns a default value (e.g. `false`, `0`, `null`).